# how to display a single vendor to its related product in django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

well, I am a beginner but a mid-level beginner and I am building an e-commerce website. I have vendor, customer and products which relate to a specific vendor. I have made a view to display the all kind of products on the page and I have also parsed the Vendor model in products view. but I am getting all vendors on a single product which shows that code is not working well as it should have. I hope you guys got the point what I want to ask?
for convenience here is  the code.

views.py:

```
def products(request):
    vendor = Vendor.objects.all()
    products_list = Item.objects.all()
    context = {
        'vendors': vendor,
        'products': products_list,
    }
    template = 'vstore/products.html'
    return render(request, template, context)
```

products.html:

```
<div class="row">
        {% for item in products %}
        <div class="col-3">
            <div class="item">
                <div class="strip">
                    <figure>
                        {% if item.discount >= 20 %}
                        <span class="ribbon off">{{item.discount}}% OFF</span>
                        <a href="{% url 'product_detail_view' item.pk %}" class="strip_info">
                            <img class="" src="{{ item.image.url }}" alt="Vendor's Photo">
                        </a>
                        {% else %}
                        <a href="{% url 'product_detail_view' item.pk %}" class="strip_info">
                            <img class="" src="{{ item.image.url }}" alt="Vendor's Photo">
                        </a>
                        {% endif %}
                    </figure>
                    <ul>
                        <li><span class="loc_open">{{ item.name }}</span></li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="score "><div class="score "><span class="">{% for vendor in vendors %}{{vendor.name}}{% endfor %}<h5><div class="item_title"><small>AED {{item.price}}</small></div></h5></span><strong>C</strong></div></div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}

    </div>
```

my models.py:

```
class Vendor(models.Model):  # this is to create a new model for restaurant
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                related_name='vstore')  # OneToOneField  is to ensure that one user have only one restarant.
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    logo = models.ImageField(upload_to='vstore_logo/', blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Item(models.Model):
    vstore = models.ForeignKey(Vendor, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Categories, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    childcategory = models.ForeignKey(ChildCategories, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    subchildcategory = models.ForeignKey(SubChildCategories, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    short_description = models.CharField(max_length=82)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='Sheesha_images/', blank=False)
    price = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    discount = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True, blank=True)
    long_description = models.TextField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
    weight = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    size = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    base = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Comment: You want to list vendors related to that item, right? Can you share your models so we can see what kind of relationship they've between them?

Comment: I am posting my models in the comment section one by one

Comment: I have edited my question. niw you can check my models as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the vendor object related to that item `{{item.vstore.name}}`. So I think it will work if you update your code like this;

```
<div class="row">
        {% for item in products %}
        <div class="col-3">
            <div class="item">
                <div class="strip">
                    <figure>
                        {% if item.discount >= 20 %}
                        <span class="ribbon off">{{item.discount}}% OFF</span>
                        <a href="{% url 'product_detail_view' item.pk %}" class="strip_info">
                            <img class="" src="{{ item.image.url }}" alt="Vendor's Photo">
                        </a>
                        {% else %}
                        <a href="{% url 'product_detail_view' item.pk %}" class="strip_info">
                            <img class="" src="{{ item.image.url }}" alt="Vendor's Photo">
                        </a>
                        {% endif %}
                    </figure>
                    <ul>
                        <li><span class="loc_open">{{ item.name }}</span></li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="score "><div class="score "><span class="">{{item.vstore.name}}<h5><div class="item_title"><small>AED {{item.price}}</small></div></h5></span><strong>C</strong></div></div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}

    </div>
```

Comment: sir nothing happend. showing me the same answer.

Comment: sorry sir. it worked with the method you mentioned in your answer.

Comment: but i was thinking that it should be iterate over and then display the vendor name?

Comment: can you explain your solution please?

Comment: Foreignkey actually means a Many-to-one relationship. In your example, Vendor is on many, and Item is on one side. So an Item object can only have one Vendor, but Vendor can have more than one Item. Django allows you to access Vendor as an attribute in its ORM. So you can access the only Vendor object related to it from an Item object as above. You can use it in the same way in Django template. You can read the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/) for more information.